# Why is this CRC not a 2 byte string?

Tags: python, binary, crc

using this string "000016037000" and this CRC16 function, the result is not a 2 byte string, why is that ?

```
def _crc16(data, bits=8):
    """private method: for calculating the CRC
    based on the standard EN50463-4

    Arguments:
        Input: data in ASCII encoding !
        Output: CRC of the data
    """
    crc = 0xFFFF
    for l in list(data):
        """or exclusive
        bin: gives the binary representation
        int: cast the string to an int with the base2
        ord: gives the ASCII code for the caracter between (0..255)
        """
        crc = crc ^ int(bin(ord(l)), 2)
        for bit in range(0, bits):
            if (crc & 0x0001) == 0x0001:
                crc = ((crc >> 1) ^ 0xA001)
            else:
                crc = crc >> 1

    return _typecasting(crc)


def _typecasting(crc):
    """gives the msb and lsb"""
    msb = hex(crc >> 8)
    lsb = hex(crc & 0x00FF)

    return lsb + msb

data = "000016037000"

print _crc16(data)
```

This is the result: 0x00xfc, when you strip the '0x' is 0fc ! a CRC16 is supposed to genrate a checksum of 2 Bytes, is it normal that the lsb is 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's normal. It's just like `0` in `10`. BTW, your main loop is a bit too verbose, how about:

```
crc = 0xFFFF
for l in data:
    crc ^= ord(l)
    for bit in range(0, bits):
        if crc & 1:
            crc = (crc >> 1) ^ 0xA001
        else:
            crc >>= 1
```

The `typecasting` function, which appears to swap the lsb and msb can be written more concisely as

```
def byteswap(crc):    
    return (crc >> 8) | (crc & 0x00FF) << 8
```

Note that to avoid hassle, both functions should work with integers only, no need for `hex` or `bin`.

Comment: Thank you @Georg, yours is more clean !

Answer (score 1):

The `hex()` function returns a string with `0x` on the front of it. So in your `typecasting` function, you have:

```
lsb = "0x00"
msb = "0xfc"
```

When you concatenate them, you get `0x` at the front and also in the middle. You should remove the `0x` from `msb` before concatenating:

```
return lsb + msb[2:]
```

Then you'll get `0x00fc`

Comment: Thank you @Barmar, but the result should be "0x000xfc" since it is a concatenation, don't you think ?!

Comment: No. You can't have an `x` in the middle of a hex number.

Comment: You want to concatenate two 8-bit hex numbers into one 16-bit hex number.

Comment: Yes i know, but i am doing it separately here then i am concatenating:msb = hex(crc >> 8), lsb = hex(crc & 0x00FF) !?

Comment: And when you do that, you're getting a useless result. It's not a CRC because it's not a number. Hex numbers should only have `0x` at the beginning.

Comment: Hex() type is str(), when i do the msb + lsb, why is the 0 missing ?

Comment: Oh, I see the problem -- `hex` doesn't pad with leading zeroes, so you don't get 2 digits for each byte. Use @georg's answer.

Comment: Thank you, i thought hex() gives '0x00' ! I'll use @Georg answer, it is way cleaner than my code !

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have quite a few unnecessary conversions, and the question is about one of the effects. I'll try to explain them in execution order.

```
for l in list(data):
```

Here you convert a string into a list of letters, each of which is a string in itself (Python doesn't use a char data type). The reason this works is because you could iterate on the string itself; just remove the list() call.

```
    crc = crc ^ int(bin(ord(l)), 2)
```

As a side note, ord() actually gets us the ordinal number; it's not certain to be ASCII (in fact, no code >127 is in ASCII). Once we have this number, you converted it to a text representation in binary and back; being paired, both conversions are redundant.

```
msb = hex(crc >> 8)
lsb = hex(crc & 0x00FF)
return lsb + msb
```

Each call to hex() converts into a hexadecimal representation. As with bin(), this is in the form of a Python numeric literal, so they're each prefixed with 0x. Concatenating them yields a somewhat strange format (though still recoverable, it doesn't resemble any common ones). At this point it might be nice to know what you were aiming for.

One guess is that you wanted a little-endian 16 bit unsigned integer in 4-digit hexadecimal format (byte oriented hexdump). We can express that using Python's standard library:

```
import binascii, struct
le16hex = binascii.b2a_hex(struct.pack('<H', crc))
```

Here `<` marks little endian, `H` marks an unsigned 16-bit value, and b2a_hex converts from binary to hex. If we just wanted a 4-digit hex value (which incidentally matches the bigendian form) we can use `"%04x"%crc`.

However, you also ask why the result is not a two byte string. That's because you requested it in hex; struct.pack above produces exactly a two byte string. Combined with your input of an even number of digits, I'm left to wonder if you mean to process binary data (as ord and struct do) or all hexadecimal (or even octal). A little more context is required to understand this.

As for the least significant byte being 0, that's an effect of this particular string; that it is only shown with one digit is because hex() doesn't produce more than necessary. The % formatting operation can produce specific numbers of digits.

Comment: Thanks Yann for taking the time to write this long response, Yes you guessed right what i was trying to do, "wanted a little-endian 16 bit unsigned integer in 4-digit hexadecimal forma" it is required for some wired protocol I am implementing, and i have to insert a 4 byte CRC at the end of the message. As for the rest, yes bin() and int() are unnecessary but i wrote the hole thing after some reflection time and i had to check the result each time to understand where was i going ! FYI the data is pure ASCII, nothing else. Cheers mate !